# Excel VBA Multiple if then calculations for one cell result

Tags: excel, if-statement, vba

Trying to apply a formula to a cell if criteria is met. Macro will first search sheet to find all and keep all rows if initials appear in columns D thru G.  In my macro I am looking for initials RPR (other initials will be in NO).   If it finds RPR in D but not in E then the calculation should be K*0.3.  If that is not the case, then I need to move on and look for the 2nd scenario and so on.  I attached an image of a table as I'm not sure what I posted below will show up correctly.  [table of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6q1Jr.jpg)

```
D     E             K       N 
RPR   NO           2000     result (K*0.3)
NO    RPR          1000     result (K*0.3) 
RPR   (blank)      1000     result (K*0.5)
RPR   RPR          2000     result (K*0.5)
NO    no           2000     result  0
No    (Blank)      2000     result  0
```

I have played with many different formats and cannot get anything to work.  This is where I am at.  I have been on this now for over a day and could really use some assistance.  I don't think I need to have anything for the zero's as the cell can be empty if it does not meet the other criterias.

```
   Dim lrow As Long
   lrow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row

   Range("N2:N" & lrow).Formula = "=IF(D2 = ""RPR"") AndIF (F2 = ""RPR"" Or"""") 
       then N2 = (K2 * 0.5,0)"

   Range("N2:N" & lrow).Formula = "IF D2 = ""RPR"" AndIF E2 <> ""RPR"" Then N2 = 
       (K2 * 0.3)"

   Range("N2:N" & lrow).Formula = "IF D2 <> ""RPR"" AndIF E2 = ""RPR"" Then N2 = 
       (K2*0.3)"

   Range("N2:N" & lrow).Value = Range("N2:N" & lrow).Value
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sub sum()
Dim lrow As Long
lrow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
'\\assuming you are starting with row 1
For r = 1 to lrow
if range("D"& r) = "RPR" and (range("F"& r) = "RPR" or isempty(range("F"& _
r)) then range("N"& r) = 0.5 * range("K"& r)
elseif range("D"& r) = "RPR" and range("F"& r) <> "RPR" then range("N"& _
r) = 0.3 * range("K"& r)
elseif range("D"& r) <> "RPR" and range("E"& r) = "RPR" then range("N"& _
r) = 0.3 * range("K"& r)
next r
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you but this will not account for the IF component of the problem.  I need it to multiply times 0.3 if "D= RPR and E does not = RPR" and also  if "D does not = RPR and E does = RPR"

Comment: I updated the code by adding a couple of more elseif's.

Comment: I keep getting a compile error Else without If, the 2nd word "range" is highlighted on the first Elseif statement.  I did try adding () around the statement, but that didn't help.

Comment: I have gotten the code to run now thank your for your help.  The problem was my placement of return after "THEN" as well as an end If statement.

Comment: This is what the code looked like with the final tweaking

Comment: Dim lrow As Long
lrow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
'\\assuming you are starting with row 1
For r = 1 To lrow

If Range("D" & r) = "RPR" And (Range("E" & r) = "RPR" Or IsEmpty(Range("E" & r))) Then
    Range("N" & r) = 0.5 * Range("K" & r)
ElseIf Range("D" & r) = "RPR" And Range("E" & r) <> "RPR" Then
    Range("N" & r) = 0.3 * Range("K" & r)
ElseIf Range("D" & r) <> "RPR" And Range("E" & r) = "RPR" Then
    Range("N" & r) = 0.3 * Range("K" & r)
End If
Next r